# How to deal with state changes in functions with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component:

```
export class Test extends React.Component<TestProps, TestState> {
   ...
   //the constructor sets the state initially
   constructor(props: TestProps) {
      this.state = {
         thisIsAState: 1;
      }
   }
   //this function updates the state given the num param
   updateState(num) {
      this.setState({ thisIsAState: num });
   }

}
```

So now in jest/enzyme test file, I have:

```
/*wrapped in a describe/it...*/

const wrapper = await mount(<Test {..anyPropsHere} />);   
wrapper.instance().updateStates(3);                           //updating the states here via function call
wrapper.update();                                             //tried this to see if it would update anything
expect(wrapper.state().thisIsAState).toEqual(3);
```

This doesn't work -> it sees the "State" variable of wrapper as null - *always*. Even if I directly setState() here, it doesn't work - still null.

I have also tried SetTimeout functions and using await, but the unit tests seem to skip those:
They complete and pass, but if I say .toEqual(4) expecting the obvious 1 !== 4 error, it will still pass, so it's somehow not hitting those functions. I have also tried shallow rendering the object as well.

Is there a proper way to call Test's update function, have it update the states, then check the states?

I am on:
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.13.1",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. You don't need to call `wrapper.update()` method and use `async/await` with `mount()`.

E.g.

`Test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface TestProps {}
export interface TestState {
  thisIsAState: number;
}

export class Test extends React.Component<TestProps, TestState> {
  constructor(props: TestProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      thisIsAState: 1,
    };
  }
  updateState(num) {
    this.setState({ thisIsAState: num });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.thisIsAState}</div>;
  }
}
```

`Test.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { Test } from './Test';

describe('66582685', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Test />);
    // @ts-ignore
    wrapper.instance().updateState(3);
    expect(wrapper.state('thisIsAState')).toEqual(3);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('3');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66582685/Test.test.tsx
  66582685
    ✓ should pass (27 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Test.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.775 s, estimated 4 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```